# Handling errors in TextFieldParser

Tags: vb.net, csv, textfieldparser

I have a VB .Net winforms app which parses a CSV file and adds the parsed lines to a table structure.

```
Dim table As New List(Of String())

Using afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)
    afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Do While Not afile.EndOfData
        Try
            Dim record As String() = afile.ReadFields()
            table.Add(record)
        Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
            If ex.Message.Contains("cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters") Then
                Dim textToReplace As String = "(?<!,)""(?!,)"
                Dim fixedString As String = Regex.Replace(afile.ErrorLine, textToReplace, "'")
            End If
        End Try
    Loop
End Using
```

The problem is that sometimes the CSV is malformed and contains a double quote in the middle of a string. So something like:

```
123,456,"abcde",100
789,098,"fg"hij",101  <--- problem line
765,432,"klmno",102
```

That's why I have the error handler which catches the error and fixes the offending double quote by converting it to a single quote. The problem is that by the time I have fixed the problem, I don't know what the rest of the line was. Because there was a problem with the line, nothing got read in at all. I do  have access to the offending field via the Error object, but that's about it. And unfortunately, even though there was an error, the TextFieldParser moved to the next line anyway. Is there a way to go back one line?

Comment: It seems that once you have fixed the ErrorLine you could add it to the list and continue

Comment: Strange, in your code you have not set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `True`. But then your code should read all lines without exception. The `MalformedLineException` is only raised if it is `True`.

Comment: You can't read the previous line because the `TextFieldParser` uses a forwrd only stream and `ReadFields` advances the reader to the next line.

Comment: Now you have edited your question so that `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` is `True`. The question is: does this corrupt file contain a comma(which is the delimiter) in any field? If not, you could simply set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `False`.

Comment: Wow I'm such an idiot! Sorry for wasting your time guys... Thanks Steve - you're absolutely right

Comment: Steve is correct, aFile.ErrorLine contains the entire line - not just the offending field.... so it's not really an issue. I don't know why I thought that aFile.ErrorLine just contained the error section/field - not the entire error line...

Comment: @Tim - valid point Tim - however, I can't be guaranteed that there won't be commas inside the string fields...